# No response to applications after a month?

Tags: support, jobs

As a candidate, I've sent 3 job applications about a month ago. I've not had any sort of response since then. Is it common for job applications to go this long without being followed up on or rejected?

Comment: Do all three appear in your Sent Messages screen? (ruling out the option they were never sent in the first place :))

Comment: Yes, they show up in Sent. Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing screams initiative like dropping by their office unexpected with donuts (and resumes) :P

Comment: Unfortunately that would require a ~$900 air ticket in my case :)

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-pro/348608#348608

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's common, but it's possible.  I see three possible explanations related to your application:

1. All three of the jobs you applied to were extremely popular.  300+ applications for all of them (with one getting 600 over 3 months).  The company could be overwhelmed, or only replying to candidates that make it to interviews.  We don't have a ton of visibility into the companies process at this point, although it's not a bad idea for us to start policing that a bit.
2. Most of these are remote positions, however the time zone difference could be an issue.  Some companies have no problem with this, but others still give preference to candidates within a certain time zone.  We've thought some about this and will probably start giving companies more room to describe what type of remote work they mean (remote in the US, remote preferred in the US, truly remote anywhere in the world etc...)
3. The companies don't have a policy to respond to all applicants.  It happens.

There are medium term projects we're working on to make the candidate experience better.  At the very least, you deserve resolution to the process after applying.

Comment: The fine-grained specification of what locations are OK for remote workers would be VERY useful, I strongly support that!

Comment: `We've thought some about this and will probably start giving companies more room to describe what type of remote work they mean (remote in the US, remote preferred in the US, truly remote anywhere in the world etc...)` Any update on this yet? To me that seems like an easy to implement feature with a lot of benefits for everyone.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, unfortunately that is the case quite often. In some cases you actually got rejected and will *never* receive a formal rejection.

A few months back I applied for jobs at Rockstar Games and Naughty Dog. From Naughty Dog I still have not received any feedback. From Rockstar I got the "Not Selected" tag a week ago (April) while having sent my application in December last year.

Another application I sent got answered 3 days later, I got invited to an interview 2 weeks later and had my first work day on the 1st of April. The entire application process from initial contact to signing a contract took less than three weeks.

It highly depends on the company you are applying for and what their internal policy regarding applications is. They are not obligated to send you a rejection, while it may be more polite doing so.

If the company you are applying at thinks you are competent they will most likely save your application and maybe get in contact at a later point in time if new job positions open up that may fit your profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Don't worry! In a lot of cases companies will continue collecting applications for jobs while the application window is open. I wouldn't think Stack Exchange would be any different.

In a lot of cases they won't start calling applicants until that window is closed and the job is removed for applications sites, etc. This can take some time. Be patient and whatever you do do not call them following up!