# Allow companies to specify a more fine-grained "allows remote" option

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In [this answer to an otherwise unrelated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253288/136880), Careers site director [Will Cole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/184698/will-cole) says:

> We (...) will probably start giving companies
>   more room to describe what type of remote work they mean (remote in
>   the US, remote preferred in the US, truly remote anywhere in the world
>   etc...)

This would be a VERY good idea since many times we open an apparently remote-workers-friendly job for a company located in another country, only to read something like "At this time we accept remote candidates from (the US/Elbonia/Wherever) only".

The three options suggested by Will seem reasonable enough to start with (changing "the US" for the country where the company is located, of course).