# Separation of remote and work from home

Tags: feature-request, jobs, site-recommendation

Careers currently only have "Allows Remote" option and it is rather unclear. Some postings are marked "Allows Remote" but only allows work from home from time to time.

Many businesses now are remote based, meaning that there is no requirement to be in the office and sometimes there is no real office at all.

I suggest "Allows Remote" is used for businesses like this, while "Work From Home" is added only for businesses that allows occasional work from home options.

Another reason for this is that business that only allows "Work From Home" is bound to a geographical location and is not a fully remote or distributed company.

Comment: Related: [Allow companies to specify a more fine-grained "allows remote" option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268225/allow-companies-to-specify-a-more-fine-grained-allows-remote-option)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see a remote job that is "work from home from time to time", please flag it.  We work with employers to make sure only jobs that are completely remote are using that designation.

That doesn't mean that the company has to be fully remote or distributed, but that *you* will be fully remote.

As to the "Work From Home" option.  This is one of the oldest unsolved problems we have, and we really do need to solve it.  There are so many varieties of remote work in addition to the two you mention where a company may have preferences based on country, city, or timezone.  They may need you to check in at headquarters once a quarter etc...  It's hard to capture all these in a structured way that's not misleading to someone in some scenario.

So for now, remote means the candidate can be fully remote.  If there are other specifications, we ask the company to use the free text in the job description.

And of course, we need to prioritize this problem and think about it more.

Comment: Awesome Will, I know there must be challenges, I am just raising the issue as a user. Keep up the good work.